# In Firebase v9, how can I filter clothes list items by category title or default to all?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an app and I am trying to allow a user to filter items based on a category titles or view all. With this code, I able to get all the items that have been added by a given user, but I'd like to be able to filter by category as well, and show all the items if no category is selected.

```
export const ClothingListItems = ({ category }) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const userUid = auth.currentUser.uid;
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  //getting items where closetceator Uid == userUid
  const getClosetAsync = async ({category}) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const q = query(
        collection(db, "clothing"),
        where("closetOwerUid", "==", userUid)
      );

      onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
        let results = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          results.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
        });
        setItems(results);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      setIsError(error.message);
    }
  };

  // Keep track with changes in data add or delete. Clean up!
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = getClosetAsync();
    return () => unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return isLoading ? (
    <LoadingIndicator />
  ) : isError || !items.length ? (
    <>
      <Error />
      <EmptyView message="Your closet is empty, add items." marginSize={65} />
    </>
  ) : (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <>
        <FlatList
          data={items}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          numColumns={2}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <ClothingItem items={item} />}
        />
      </>
    </View>
  );
};
```

[image: database]

Comment: Can you also include what is your use case? How do you plan to filter the items? On that note, have you already checked this documentation on [Filtering Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering)?

Comment: So, when a user clicks on a button that has a value, such as shoes, this component (getClosetAsync) obtains that value. I double-checked that the component receives it and it does. However, the issue is that I can't seem to figure out how to get Firebase filter in accordance with that. 

I even went as far as chaining multiple equality operators: 
```
const q = query(clothingItemsRef, where("closet_id", "==", "yourId"), where("category_id", "==", "pants") ); ```
but i get nothing in return.

Comment: Upon checking your code, it lacks the proper data structure. Can you provide your sample data structure that also includes a sample of "category", "category_id", and "closed_id"? Lastly, please update your reproducible code accordingly.